# My page is "stuttering" when it loads. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a piece of content that I was tired of editing on every page of my website, so I put it in a separate `HTML` file and have been loading the markup into its place on all my pages:

```
<div id="header-house">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#header-house").load("reusableMarkup/header.html");         
    </script>
</div>
```

The problem is that my page stutters when it loads. It seems to load everything and then display it and then move it around after injecting the header. Is there any simple fix to this? I haven't yet learned synch/asynch stuff.

Comment: Use a server side language to include the header instead.

Comment: @Marty: Can you (1) Explain why and (2) give me a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediate asynchronous calls to retrieve bits and bobs of HTML isn't the correct way to go about what you are trying to do - a separate HTTP request must be made for each additional HTML file you want to include, slowing your site down significantly and creating a weird user experience like you've described.

The route you've taken here is better suited to on-demand HTML generation (e.g. when the user performs an action that results in a popup modal containing some dynamic data).

What you're trying to do is *exactly* what a server-side language is used for, where your HTML files are combined / repeated on the server to generate a single HTML document, which is then sent to the client as a whole (one HTTP request).

In [PHP](http://php.net/) for example, you could go about solving your problem using the [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function:

```
<div id="header-house">
    <?php include "reusableMarkup/header.html"; ?>
</div>
```